# How to use the ResourceManager web interface as an user

Tags: hadoop, resourcemanager

Every time i try to use the Hadoop Resource Manager web interface (http://resource-manger.host:8088/cluster/) i show up logged in as dr.who.

My question, how can I login as another user? In this case i want to login as myself and have a higher lever of privileges than dr.who.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The user infomation is got from HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser().
1. If you deployed an insecure cluster, the simplest way to pass the username to server is by url parameter. For example, http://localhost:8088/cluster?user.name=babu
2. If you deployed a secure cluster, you probably use Kerberos authentication. You can use *kinit* to get a kerberos tgt, then configure the browser to negotiate. (*network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris* for firefox, and *--auth-server-whitelist* for chromium. I'm sure there's lots of answers about this)

For more information, you can check hadoop official documentation.(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the access control list by changing the default configuration of:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.zk-acl
```

from

```
world:anyone:rwcda
```

to something else,which is Cluster-specific

The ACLs the ResourceManager uses for the znode structure to store the internal state.