# YARN REST API custom user to run the job instead of dr.who

Tags: api, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

What do I need in order to provide a user that runs this job as? For example when I do `hadoop jar ...`  - the user logged in is used as the user to submit the job. How can I do the same with YARN REST API?

Thanks for your help. I googled around but the examples and documentation does not talk about it. The job runs as dr.who.

Regards,
Atul.

Comment: You'll probably need a Kerberized cluster to support that

Comment: The documentation does not say that ... :( I am just wondering how does the hadoop jar command do this without thee kerberized cluster?

Comment: The `hadoop jar` command reads files values such as `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and `HADOOP_USER_NAME`. If you export either of those to a different value, your job is submitted by a different account. The web API does not read environment variable.

Comment: I would assume this works the same way as the web interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121402/how-to-use-the-resourcemanager-web-interface-as-an-user